# Pass data back from previos VC if segue already in use

Tags: ios, swift

I have VC "A", from which I pass some data to "B". In attribute inspector i called my seque "B" :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "B" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! ChooseController
            vc.someData = "passedDataFromAToB"
    }
```

After that i want to pass some data back from B to A using delegates and protocols, but it turns out that my segue identifier is busy. I have to create new segue? But how, programmatically?

Comment: You can use unwind segues. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839298/1077789) answer.

Comment: Use delegate method to pass data back from VC "B" to VC "A", then dismiss the VC "B"

Comment: You can use `closures` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the delegate here

```
let vc = segue.destination as! ChooseController
vc.delegate = self
vc.someData = "passedDataFromAToB"
```

---

```
class ChooseController:UIViewController {
  weak var delegate:AVC?
```

then to pass data before dismiss

```
delegate?.sendData(data)
self.dismiss(animated:true,completion:nil)
```